# How to get latest post using setInterval function and ajax and prepend it to some html element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I already get the array value from my php file. What I want to do is post the value of an array in some html element and post it every x seconds. I don't know how to start.

```
setInterval(getNewPost, 2000);

function getNewPost(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'newpost.php',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function(data){
             $.each(data, function(k,v)){
                   $('<div class="someclass">'+v.Data+'</div>').prependTo('.latest');
              }
       }

    });

}
```

IN that CODE above, it prepends the data and duplicate it every 2 seconds. what I want to do is just prepend the data w/o duplicating the data.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to be way more specific and show a little code at least?

Comment: @Isuckatprogramming see code above. THank you

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, I would suggest that when you hit `newpost.php', you should also send the ID of the latest post you've retrieved. That way, your backend only needs to return records which you haven't already retrieved.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie How to do that?

Comment: Well, I don't know what your `newpost.php` page returns, but assuming posts have an ID, you can cache the value of the last ID you retrieved, then include it in your request, i.e. `url: 'newpost.php?lastId=XXX`. Note that since you're just retrieving posts, it's probably more appropriate for your request to be a GET, not a POST